# Kibana4: Analyzed string field warning

Tags: json, kibana, kibana-4, elasticsearch

I have 3 JSON key value pairs in my document which I insert into elasticsearch and visualize using Kibana4.The 3 JSON keys are `NT`,`XT`and `YT`. The values are typically integers between 100 and 1000 for all the three keys. Some typical values are `543`,`328` and `753`. When I visualize the keys in Kibana4 I get the below warning for each of the above three keys.

`This is an analyzed string field.Analyzed string fields are highly unique and can use a lot of memory to visualize`

In an attempt to fix the above problem I have used the below shell script to create a mapping for the `document type` in elastic search that contain these keys.

My elasticsearch index is `bits` and my document type is `nts` and I am trying to assign type `long` for 3 JSON keys in the document of type `nts`
namely `NT`, `XT` and `YT`.

```
#!/bin/bash

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/bits/nts/_mapping' -d '
{
        "events" : {
            "dynamic" : "strict",
            "properties" : {
                "NT" : {
                        type : "long" 
                 },
                "XT" : {
                        type : "long" 
                 },
                "YT"  : {
                        type : "long" 
                }
            }
        },
}'
```

The above mapping doesn't fix the problem and I am still getting the `analyzed string field` warning. Can someone point out what could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that your fields actually get indexed as integers (i.e. no quotes around the numbers) by checking individual indexed documents JSON on Discover tab in Kibana.

You may need to change how your application indexes data. index.mapping.ignore_malformed and index.mapping.coerce setting described [here](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/mapping.html) may also be of help.

Also try going to Settings -> Indices ->  and clicking the "Reload field list" button in Kibana since it caches field types.

And finally, if you're using timestamped index patterns (like [logstash-]YYYY.MM.DD) you may need to rename or delete old indexes where your fields are indexed as strings